# how to use loops to access form elements in C#?

Tags: c#

```
  if(pictureBox1.Tag.ToString() == "accept")
        {
            char room1 = Convert.ToChar(lbl_roomid1.Text);
            row1[13] = (byte)room1;

            DateTime sdt1 = DateTime.Parse(txt_sdate1.Text);
            //some code
         }
  if (pictureBox2.Tag.ToString() == "accept")
        {
            char room2 = Convert.ToChar(lbl_roomid2.Text);
            row1[13] = (byte)room2;

            DateTime sdt1 = DateTime.Parse(txt_sdate2.Text);
            //some code
         }
```

/* What if i wanted to type this code inside a loop?? i need to do the same for 10 pictureboxes */

Comment: Try to use for loop if possible. Because the foreach works for an object collection that implements the IEnumerable interface. You can not use foreach to add or remove items from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects. If you need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a for loop.

Comment: @Shee Follow up: if you got the answer you were looking for, don't forget to mark it as correct. Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    public void DoMagic(Label label, TextBox textBox)
    {
        //...
    }
```

And this:

```
        foreach (Control currentControl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (currentControl is PictureBox)
            {
                if (((PictureBox)currentControl).Tag.ToString().Equals("accept"))
                {
                    string controlId = currentControl.Name.Remove(0, 11);
                    string labelName = string.Concat("lbl_roomid", controlId);
                    string txtName = string.Concat("txt_sdate", controlId);

                    this.DoMagic(this.Controls.Find(labelName, true)[0] as Label, this.Controls.Find(txtName, true)[0] as TextBox);
                }
            }
        }
```

Regards

Comment: Do note that the OP's loop has separate labels and textboxes for each case too.

Answer (score 2):

You could make an array of the elements.

The following is a little dirty, but...

```
class PBRoomDate {
  // Helper data holder class. Could probably be an anonymous class in C# 4.0
  public PictureBox PB;
  public Label RoomLabel;
  public TextBox DateText;
  PBRoomDate(PictureBox PB, Label RoomLabel, TextBox DateText) {
    this.PB = PB; this.RoomLabel = RoomLabel; this.DateText = DateText;
  }
}

// [...]

var pbRoomDates = new PBRoomDate[]{
  new PBRoomDate(pictureBox1, lbl_roomid1, txt_sdate1),
  new PBRoomDate(pictureBox2, lbl_roomid2, txt_sdate2),
  new PBRoomDate(pictureBox3, lbl_roomid3, txt_sdate3),
  // etc.
};

foreach(var pbRoomDate in pbRoomDates) {
  if(pbRoomDate.PB.Tag.ToString() == "accept") {
    row1[13] = (byte)Convert.ToChar(pbRoomDate.RoomLabel.Text);
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(pbRoomDate.DateText.Text);
  }
}
```

The cleaner solution would be to use a custom UserControl to contain the three elements per "picturebox" and lay those out. That would also be easier to maintain and more extendable should the need arise.

Answer (score 0):

Loops to access form elements in c#.

I usually use something like this.

Let say i have 10 picturebox i name it picturebox1 - picturebox10.

Then 
    Do a loop for the number to loop to 10 i use a variable no
     inside it put this code

```
String Picturebox = "picturebox" + no.ToString();
Control[] oControl = Controls.Find(Picturebox, true);
foreach(Control foundControl in oControl)
{
  PictureBox foundControlA = foundControl as PictureBox;
  foundControlA.(methods or property here) = (what you want to put to foundControlA)

}
```

If you have more controls accompanied by each control you can use the same method. The hint here is that i use the same naming convention on my elements or object in my winforms and loop the variable no according to what you want.